# Query to get a register same value in a column and different in other column

Tags: oracle, plsql

If I have a table like these:

```
Name Direction
A    B
A    C
A    B
B    D
B    E
```

I would like to get the register(s) with same name and direction different. In these case:

```
Name Direction
A    B
```

I'm tryng with group by but I can't do it. Someone could help me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` together, like this:

```
select Name, min(Direction), max(Direction)
from table
group by Name
having min(Direction) <> max(Direction)
```

Comment: Well. I put a example with number but really the two columns values are strings (varchar2)

Comment: min() and max() work the same with any data type - the only requirement of the query is that a given Name has rows with multiple (i.e different) values in the Direction column